# Testing Phoenix channels (for chat) over iex

Tags: sockets, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the standard (canonical?) [Phoenix chat example](https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example) to build something. But because I'm going to be handling the back-end only, I don't want to go through the trouble of wrestling with JavaScript on the client side. I'd like to test my room creation and broadcast over 3-4 terminal sessions, which will act as users.

So here's what I tried straightaway:

```
iex(2)> Rtc.RoomChannel.join("rooms:gossip", "hey!", {})
{:ok, {}}
```

Hmmm, that's weird. I was supposed to get back a socket. Wait a minute! Silly me, I just passed an empty tuple instead of a socket, and got it back. Which means I just need to pass a valid socket as the third parameter. Cool! . . .

But how to get a socket? I then remembered that we have something called the user_socket in the channels directory, so I tried something like this:

```
iex(5)> h MyApp.UserSocket.connect
@callback connect(params :: map(), Phoenix.Socket.t()) :: {:ok, Phoenix.Socket.t()} | :error
```

Aha! Now I know how to create sockets. So let's create one:

```
iex(6)> MyApp.UserSocket.connect(%{}, Phoenix.Socket.t())
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Phoenix.Socket.t/0
    (phoenix) Phoenix.Socket.t()
```

And indeed, there's no `t()` function in the `Phoenix.Socket` module.

Where have I gone wrong? Is it even possible to create sockets like this, or am I doomed to have a JavaScript client?

Comment: I don't know if this will fix all the problems but the correct way to create  a struct is not `Foo.t()` but `%Foo{}`, so in this case, try `%Phoenix.Socket{}`?

Comment: @Dogbert Nice! That seems to generate a valid socket. I wonder how you deduced the correct data structure, given that the documentation itself says `t()`. Could you please explain that add both things as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at `Phoenix.Socket` module.This is how `connect/2` callback is defined:

```
...
alias Phoenix.Socket

@callback connect(params :: map, Socket.t) :: {:ok, Socket.t} | :error

...
  @type t :: %Socket{id: nil,
                     assigns: %{},
                     channel: atom,
                     channel_pid: pid,
                     endpoint: atom,
                     handler: atom,
                     joined: boolean,
                     pubsub_server: atom,
                     ref: term,
                     topic: String.t,
                     transport: atom,
                     transport_name: atom,
                     serializer: atom,
                     transport_pid: pid}
```

[Typespecs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/typespecs.html#content)

> Remote types
>
> Any module is also able to define its own types and the modules in
>   Elixir are no exception. For example, the Range module defines a t
>   type that represents a range: this type can be referred to as Range.t.
>   In a similar fashion, a string is String.t, any enumerable can be
>   Enum.t, and so on.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. Looks like there's no running away from advanced features of Elixir!